# How to get the size of a partition (window) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

When I use a window, how can I get the size (number of rows) of the current partition?

For instance let's say I have a table that holds the comments of posts in a blog. I would like to know for each post what is the first comment, second comment, last comment and number of comments (without having another sub-query where I group by post and do `COUNT(*)`).

The query should look something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    post_id.
    first_value(comment_text) OVER wnd AS first_comment,
    nth_value(comment_text, 2) OVER wnd AS second_comment,
    last_value(comment_text) OVER wnd AS last_comment,
    SOME_FUNCTION(comment_text) OVER wnd AS number_of_comments
FROM comments
WINDOW wnd AS (
    PARTITION BY post_id
    ORDER BY comment_created_at ASC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
);
```

What should **`SOME_FUNCTION`** be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's right there in your question, once you realise you can use it with windows: `COUNT(*) OVER wnd AS number_of_comments` will do the job.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    post_id.
    first_value(comment_text) OVER wnd AS first_comment,
    nth_value(comment_text, 2) OVER wnd AS second_comment,
    last_value(comment_text) OVER wnd AS last_comment,
    COUNT(*) OVER wnd AS number_of_comments
FROM comments
WINDOW wnd AS (
    PARTITION BY post_id
    ORDER BY comment_created_at ASC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
);
```

Comment: Huh, I guess it was one of those cases that just writing the question, brought me (almost) to the answer. Thank you.